# Chat TCP java sockets

Tags: java, netbeans, tcp

Estoy intentando hacer un programa tipo chat. Tengo 2 clientes y 1 servidor. Mi problema es que si escribo mensajes del chat 1 al chat 2 no tengo problemas pero si mando mensajes del chat 2 al chat 1 no sale nada, pero si se lo manda al servidor,

Imagen 1[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagen 2:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clase cliente:

```
public class Cliente extends JFrame {


    public Cliente() {
        setBounds(600, 300, 280, 400);
        LaminaMarcoCliente milamina = new LaminaMarcoCliente();
        add(milamina);
        setVisible(true);


    }

}
```

Clase LaminaMarcoCliente:

```
class LaminaMarcoCliente extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private JTextField campo1, nick;
    private JButton miboton;
    private JTextArea areadechat;

    public LaminaMarcoCliente() {

        nick = new JTextField(5);
        add(nick);

        JLabel texto = new JLabel("CLIENTE");
        add(texto);

        areadechat = new JTextArea(16, 21);
        add(areadechat);

        campo1 = new JTextField(20);
        add(campo1);
        miboton = new JButton("Enviar");
        EnviaTexto mievento = new EnviaTexto();
        miboton.addActionListener(mievento);
        add(miboton);

        Thread hilocliente = new Thread(this);
        hilocliente.start();

    }

    private class EnviaTexto implements ActionListener {

        private DataOutputStream flujoDeSalida;

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {



            try {

                Socket socketcliente = new Socket("localhost", 9999);

                //Instancio la clase Mensaje
                Mensaje mensaje = new Mensaje();
                //Utilizo los getter y setters Clase Mensaje y pasamos lo que hay escrito en el cuadro de texto nick, ip y mensaje
                mensaje.setNick(nick.getText());
                mensaje.setMensaje(campo1.getText());
                //Utilizamos ObjectStream para enviar un objeto
                ObjectOutputStream datos = new ObjectOutputStream(socketcliente.getOutputStream());
                //Indicamos el objeto que queremos enviar
                datos.writeObject(mensaje);

                socketcliente.close();
                /*flujoDeSalida= new DataOutputStream(socketcliente.getOutputStream());
                //Escribe en el flujo lo que hay en el campo1
                flujoDeSalida.writeUTF(campo1.getText());
                //Cerramos flujo salida
                flujoDeSalida.close();*/

            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }

        }

    }

@Override
public void run() {
    try {

        //Ponemos a la escucha el cliente
        //Creamos un canal para recibir el paquete
        Socket cliente;
        Mensaje paqueteRecibido;
        while (true) {
            //Aceptamos todos los mensajes (Conexiones)
            //Creamos un flujo de datos de entrada para transportar objetos
            ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(socketcliente.getInputStream());
            //Leemos lo que hay en el interior 
            paqueteRecibido = (Mensaje) entrada.readObject();
            //Lo escribimos en el area de texto
            areadechat.append("\n" + paqueteRecibido.getNick() + ": " + paqueteRecibido.getMensaje());
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Clase servidor:

```
class Servidor extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    private JTextArea areatexto;
    private DataInputStream flujoDeEntrada;
    private String cadenaRecibe = null;

    public Servidor() {
        setBounds(1200, 300, 280, 350);
        JPanel milamina = new JPanel();
        milamina.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        areatexto = new JTextArea();
        milamina.add(areatexto, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(milamina);
        setVisible(true);

        Thread mi_hilo = new Thread(this);
        mi_hilo.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Servidor:Estoy a la escucha");

        try {
            ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(9999);
            String nick, mensaje;
            //Creamos la instancia mensaje para recibir los datos 
            Mensaje recibir;
            while (true) {
                //Aceptar las conexiones del cliente (Exterior)       
                Socket misocket = servidor.accept();

                //Creamos un Objectinput para recibir los datos
                ObjectInputStream datos = new ObjectInputStream(misocket.getInputStream());
                //Meter dentro del objeto datos lo que le llega por la red
                recibir = (Mensaje) datos.readObject();
                //Accedemos a la informacion que hay dentro del paquete donde esta el nick y el mensaje
                nick = recibir.getNick();
                mensaje = recibir.getMensaje();

                /*flujoDeEntrada = new DataInputStream(misocket.getInputStream());
                    //Almacenamos el texto del cliente
                    cadenaRecibe= flujoDeEntrada.readUTF();
                    //Agregar el texto que recibe al textarea
                    areatexto.append("\n"+cadenaRecibe);*/
                areatexto.append("\n" + nick + ": " + mensaje);
                //Creamos otro socket para que viaje la informacion
                Socket destinatario = new Socket("localhost",9090);
                //Enviamos el paquete 
                ObjectOutputStream reenvio = new ObjectOutputStream(destinatario.getOutputStream());
                //Metemos la informacion que vamos a enviar en el ObjectOutput
                reenvio.writeObject(recibir);
                reenvio.close();
                //Cerramos socket
                destinatario.close();
                //Cerramos conexion
                misocket.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        }

    }

}
```

Clase mensaje:

```
public class Mensaje implements Serializable {

    private String nick,mensaje;

    public String getNick() {
        return nick;
    }

    public void setNick(String nick) {
        this.nick = nick;
    }

    public String getMensaje() {
        return mensaje;
    }

    public void setMensaje(String mensaje) {
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Saludos.

Deberías leer un poco más acerca de los `Sockets`, especialmente para  `Cliente - Servidor`, ver más ejemplos, tutoriales... [Un ejemplo aquí](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos-Avanzados/Java/Sockets).

Para no entrar en muchos detalles (porque explicar acerca de todo esto lleva su tiempo), lo primero que pensé al ver el código fue: **¿por qué hay dos ServerSocket?**.

Al momento de instanciar un nuevo `ServerSocket` (en tu caso esto ocurre 3 veces; una de ellas en la clase `Servidor`, y las otras 2 en los dos clientes que abres), enlazarás el `puerto` que indiques (esto se conoce como `bind`) para realizar la comunicación. **Esto obliga a que ese puerto no pueda ser utilizado mientras esté ocupado por algo o alguien (en este caso, cualquiera que utilice un ServerSocket)**.

Si intentas abrir un puerto que ya está ocupado, Java te dirá algo así:

> Address already in use: JVM_Bind

En español quiere decir que la dirección ya está en uso, es decir, algún programa ha abierto el puerto y **no puede ser abierto de nuevo**.

Si esto sucede, la acción no se realiza y por ende, no tendrás comunicación, y es precisamente lo que te ocurre.

Para evitar esto, **NO** abras dos `ServerSocket` (mucho menos 3) para realizar una misma función, en este caso (una aplicación de chat) el único que debe ser abierto es el `ServerSocket` del `Servidor`, él debe gestionar toda la información entrante y saber qué hacer con ella (esto se lo debes indicar tú). El `Cliente` únicamente, deberá enviar y recibir información a ese servidor.

Imaginalo como una estación de correo. El encargado de recibir el correo, también debe encargarse de hacer llegar el paquete a su destino, el cliente sólo deja su paquete o lo recibe.

Por otro lado, **para poder establecer una comunicación entre el cliente y el servidor**, utiliza los `I/O Stream` o flujos de entrada y salida. Esto, para enviar (por medio del `output` o `salida`) y recibir (por medio del `input` o `entrada`) los datos que el servidor recibe de ti o te envía. Creo que esto es lo que pretendías hacer con el `ServerSocket` que pusiste en el `Cliente`, pero eso no está bien, utiliza los flujos.

Para no extenderlo más y para darte una idea, reutiliza el mismo `Socket` que utilizaste para conectarte al `Servidor`, ese `Socket` te brinda los métodos `getInputStream()` y `getOutputStream()` y **NO LOS CIERRES**. Como tú pretendes crear un programa de comunicación entre clientes, el servidor necesita que los clientes estén conectados para saber a donde enviar el paquete que recibe de alguien más.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por contestar, te he entendido perfectamente pero, en el hilo del cliente que debo de poner??

Comment: El hilo del cliente debe escuchar información proveniente del `Servidor`, entonces (en tu caso como usas un `ObjectInputStream`) utiliza: `input.readObject();`

Comment: El hilo quedará detenido esperando que el servidor envíe alguna información, y cuando suceda tú debes indicarle qué hacer con ella

Comment: Es algo muy similar a lo que pusiste en el lado del `Servidor`: `recibir = (Mensaje) datos.readObject();`

Comment: En el AcctionPerfomed del boton de enviar esta bien entonces?

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta

Comment: Deberías conectarte únicamente una vez, ya que el evento ' ActionPerformed' se llama cada vez que presionas el botón, esto implica abrir el `socket` más veces. Debería estar en un `hilo`

Comment: Dberia de a ver un Socket en el AccionPerformed y otro en el RUN??

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71983/discussion-between-c-rodriguez-and-zzxbx).